# How to store image file into database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder.$filename);

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.'t_'.$filename,100);

imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($src);
```

how to store `$src` file into databse

Comment: don't, store image in file system, path to image in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, open file using [**fopen()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), read its content using **[fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)**, and then store that content to, e.g. **[BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html)** field in database.

It's always better solution to store file(s) on file system like Dagon suggested in comment.

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible I would avoid storing the image in the database.  BLOBS are rarely a good idea and are a total nightmare for portability.  I would store the image on the server and then store a reference (either just directory path or URL) to the image in the database.  I have a lot of applications that accept file uploads and I always just write the file, apply some sort of naming convention to the file and store the path/url in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read the file, base 64 encode it and store that as a string. then you may simply call the string contents and output your data as follows
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,$base64_string_contents">`